# How can I have controls in flash players used to play .swf in webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, embed

How can I add `play`, `pause`, `stop`, `full-screen` buttons, volume bar and progress bar in `embed` tag? I actually wanted to play a `'.swf'` file in my web page but all it comes is with out any controls.

If there are way with JavaScript or jQuery then please let me know about them.

I have tried using the `pluginobject` but I want to apply a skin to it. Can anyone reference to anykind of such things?

**So, I want some of you to help me solve my problem.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add something like the [FLVPlayback](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html) added to the source flv. When you republish the flash it will have playback controls on.

Or you could program your own control in using `stop()` and `start()` etc.

If you wanted to use a jQuery approach you can use jQuery SWFObject. This will embed the swf and give you a options to control some aspects of the swf. Although additional changes to the source maybe required.

You can find examples here http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/examples

Comment: Please remember to mark it as the answer if it has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if i got this right..
so you're trying to use a html5 video element to play a swf?
that doesn't make any sense to me.

here's how a standard HTML5 video tag should look

```
<video id="myvideo" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

here's how you control it by using JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var v = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
v.play();
</script>
```

other resources:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/

IF you mean having the default player controls on a flash video player...

then it's just a question of preloading a default skin to it inside flash.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/components/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7f12.html

Comment: question is how do i use it?

Comment: well, no. but you can use JS to communicate with a flash/swf on embed tag. it depends on what you need to do.  do you just need to play an swf timeline animation? is that what you want ?