# How to play/pause flash video(not html5 <video>) with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

I am looking into which should be simple actions such as playing and pausing a simple flash video with Jquery when a button or play pause button is clicked, and I can't find anything online.

```
<object style="display: block;" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.0/video-js.swf" id="video-239-video_flash_api" name="video-239-video_flash_api" class="vjs-tech" height="100%" width="100%">
```

The above object  tag is the element for the flash. My script is located at the header and the object tag is located way lower at the body. I have tried something like

```
$('#video-239-video_flash_api').get(0).play();
```

and

```
$('#video-239-video_flash_api').play();
```

but nothing works just to play and pause a flash video.

Comment: Have you researched? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240733/how-can-i-have-controls-in-flash-players-used-to-play-swf-in-webpage

Answer (score 0):

> *"...but nothing works just to play and pause a flash video."*

I think the whole selling point of VideoJS is that it makes the Flash video (FLV file) work within a browser's `<video>` tag.

The example code below is tested on Windows PC with Chrome browser. Just paste in a new html document and try it. Hopefully it gives you some useful hints.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.7/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.7/video.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>flash test</h1>

<video id="myPlayer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"  preload="auto" width="800" height="335" 
data-setup='{}'>
<source src="http://www.mediacollege.com/video-gallery/testclips/20051210-w50s.flv" type='video/x-flv'>
</video>


<button onclick="playVideo()">Play</button>
<button onclick="pauseVideo()">Pause</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

var myPlayer;

videojs("myPlayer").ready
( function() { myPlayer = this; } );

function playVideo() { myPlayer.play(); }

function pauseVideo() { myPlayer.pause(); }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```